# Is $\hat u \hat p$ also a projector if $\hat p$ is and if $\hat u$ is unitary?

Tags: hilbert-space, operators

If $\hat p:\mathcal H\to\mathcal H_p\subseteq\mathcal H$ is a projection operator, and if $\hat u$ is unitary, then it's easy/trivial to show that $\hat u \hat p \hat u^{-1}$ is also a projector.

But if we interpret unitary $\hat u$ as a rotation in $\mathcal H$, then it seems (at least to me) intuitive that $\hat u\hat p$ should also be a projector, simply rotating that $\hat p:\mathcal H\to\mathcal H_p\subseteq\mathcal H$ subspace into another subspace $\hat u:\mathcal H_p\to\mathcal H_{up}$. But I can't seem to conjure up a proof that $\hat u\hat p$ is also a projector.

So, is it true to begin with, and if so, can you provide or cite such a proof? And if not, what's the problem with that "rotation reasoning"? (All I could think up myself is that maybe the rotated $\mathcal H_p$ subspace results in a subset of $\mathcal H$ that's no longer complete with respect to scalar multiplication or vector addition, or something like that. But unless I'm wrong, it remains complete wrt those operations, and hence remains a subspace.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not true.  Projectors are, by definition, idempotent; however, in general $(\hat u\hat p)(\hat u \hat p) \neq \hat u \hat p$.  As a trivial example, let $\hat u = -\mathbb I$, which maps $\psi\in\mathcal H \mapsto -\psi$.  Since $\hat u$ commutes with everything,
$$(\hat u \hat p)(\hat u \hat p)=\hat p^2 = \hat p  \neq \hat u \hat p$$

As a second counterexample, consider $\mathcal H = \mathbb R^3$ with $\hat p = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0}$ the projection onto the $(x,y)$ plane.  If $\hat u$ is a rotation about the $z$-axis, then it should be clear that $\hat u \hat p$ will not be idempotent (unless the rotation is trivial).  Furthermore, if $\hat u$ is e.g. a $\pi/4$ rotation about the $x$-axis, then successive applications of $(\hat u \hat p)$ to the vector $\psi =\pmatrix{0\\1\\0}$ will yield a sequence of vectors

$$(\hat u \hat p)^n \psi = \pmatrix{0\\1/\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^n\\0}$$

which is certainly not the kind of behavior we'd like in a projector.

Comment: Could it possibly be a projector up to normalization?

Comment: @AndrewSteane In the $\mathbb R^3$ example, if $\hat u$ is a $\pi/2$ rotation about the $z$-axis then successive applications of $\hat u \hat p$ will rotate the vector in circles, so that doesn't work either.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder What? A single counterexample constitutes a proof that a claim is false.

Comment: These are **examples**. Not a proof, which is asked. Well, half of it. Of course, examples show that it's not true, but that doesn't constitute proof. Or does it? I like the examples though.

Comment: Of course, it does! My mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexamples. And particularly that $\hat u^n$ just amounts to successive/cumulative rotations. Duh...seems utterly obvious **>>now that you mention it<<** Thanks.

Comment: @JohnForkosh I find that the barrier between something being utterly opaque and utterly obvious is frequently a single moment of "duh" :)

Answer (score 5):

J. Murray has given you a few counterexamples, so I'll address the other part of your question.

The problem with your intuition is that if $\hat p$ is an operator, $\hat U\hat p$ is not a rotation of $\hat p$. Consider a simple projection operator $\def\ket#1{\left|#1\right\rangle}\def\bra#1{\left\langle#1\right|}\def\ketbra#1{\ket{#1}\bra{#1}}\hat p=\ketbra{\psi}$ and a unitary operator $\hat U$ such that $\ket{\psi^\prime}=\hat U\ket{\psi}$.

The operator $\ketbra{\psi}$ projects a state onto $\ket{\psi}$. So if we interpret $\hat U$ as a rotation, then we should end up with an operator that projects a state onto $\ket{\psi^\prime}$. In other words, the operator rotated is given by:

$$\hat p^\prime=\ketbra{\psi^\prime}=\ketbra{\hat U\psi}=\hat U\ketbra{\psi}\hat U^\dagger=\hat U\hat p\hat U^\dagger$$

In other words, your intuition that just rotating a projector shouldn't change the fact that it is a projector is correct. It's just that rotating a projector is not done by $\hat U\hat p$ but instead by $\hat U\hat p\hat U^\dagger$.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I (pretty obviously) looked at $\hat U\hat p\hat U^{-1}$ in the first sentence of the question due to its appearance and discussion (usually more generally wrt self-adjoint operators) in virtually every single textbook that discusses unitary operators at all. Guess I should have stopped right there, with the usual interpretation/explanation.

Comment: @JohnForkosh No problems questioning things you aren't sure of. ;) I don't think it's obvious at all why $\hat U|\psi\rangle$ can be interpreted as a rotation of $|\psi\rangle$ but $\hat U\hat p$ cannot be interpreted as a rotation of $\hat p$.